# Filtering multiple fields in object at once Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to show a list of users if any of its fields include the text that the input field has. I can get this to work if I remove the for loop in the filteredList() function and choose to manually select which it is chosen from

(ex: `return theuser.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchinput.toLowerCase());)`

but I do not want to write this over and over in case fields are taken away or added later on.

Right now I am getting 
"vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" but I am not sure what is causing this error. Could someone explain to me why this is happening? Is there a better way to make this more dynamic than having the fields i want to check in their own array?

I took the code and put in in a codepen - https://codepen.io/Jaylan_Snelson/pen/ZEbajYp?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want `theuser[shownFields[i]]` not `theuser.shownFields[i]` because `theuser` does not have a property called `shownFields`

You also what to change `i <= shownFields.length` to `i < shownFields.length` - because the length of an array is one greater than the highest index

```
return this.items.filter(function(theuser) {
    for(var i = 0; i < shownFields.length; i++) { // change here
       if(theuser[shownFields[i]].toLowerCase().includes(searchinput.toLowerCase())) { // change here
           return theuser[shownFields[i]].toLowerCase().includes(searchinput.toLowerCase()); // change here
       }
    }
});
```